# WebAPI Async Controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have problem with my ASP.NET WebAPI async controller. It looks similar like this

```
public class ItemController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems()
    {

        var dbContext = new ApplicationContext();

        var repository = new ItemRepository(dbContext);

        List<Item> list = await repository.GetItemsAsync();

        return list;
}
```

Problem is, that it returns empty list already from repository (althought there are items in db).

When I use same code

```
        var dbContext = new ApplicationContext();

        var repository = new ItemRepository(dbContext);

        List<Item> list = await repository.GetItemsAsync();
```

somewhere out of this controller, it works fine.

Can someone explain me how to fix it and why is it happening?

Comment: Is it returning an empty list in debugger or the browser?

Comment: Solved... I forgot to set connection string in Web API project config (!!!). So it created new empy one next to my valid full db.